# Installing Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE; LLVM; Virtual machine

Tags: drivers, graphics, vmware

I'm hoping good soul out there can help me with a graphics driver issue I'm having with a VM I created from a physical Ubnutu Gnome 17.04 64bit.

I'm running the VM in the latest Vmware player 12 but I'm having display scaling problems, and it looks as though the wrong graphics drivers are being used eg. this one - Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 256 bits)

I did a fresh Ubuntu VM install to compare and it's reporting Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE; LLVM; which all works fine and dandy.

Can someone please tell me how to install - Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE; LLVM;

I've looked at this link below but I'm a bit unsure. I need some guidance with the procedure.

https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/pdc.kth.se/roots/ilse/v0.7/pdc/vol/mesa/9.2.5/src/Mesa-9.2.5/docs/vmware-guest.html

**I get as far as -**

cd $TOP/vmwgfx
  make
  sudo make install
  sudo cp 00-vmwgfx.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
  sudo depmod -ae

But it gives errors -

cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:290: recipe for target '/home/ubun/vmwgfx/drm_modes.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ubun/vmwgfx/drm_modes.o] Error 1
Makefile:1488: recipe for target '*module*/home/ubun/vmwgfx' failed
make[1]: *** [*module*/home/ubun/vmwgfx] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-040900rc1-generic'
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
ubun@ubun-desktop:~/vmwgfx$   sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-040900rc1-generic/build  KCPPFLAGS="-DVMWGFX_STANDALONE -DTTM_STANDALONE" SUBDIRS=`/bin/pwd` DRMSRCDIR=`/bin/pwd` modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-040900rc1-generic'
  DEPMOD  4.9.0-040900rc1-generic
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-040900rc1-generic'
ubun@ubun-desktop:~/vmwgfx$   sudo cp 00-vmwgfx.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
cp: cannot stat '00-vmwgfx.rules': No such file or directory
ubun@ubun-desktop:~/vmwgfx$   sudo depmod -ae
depmod: WARNING: -e needs -E or -F

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found below

https://communities.vmware.com/message/2671936#2671936